# "no line here to end" and "missing $ inserted"

Tags: errors, line-breaking, compilation-error

at the moment I get a pretty simple tex error, but I don't know how to handle it: the following code (an excerpt of a larger thing but with the same error) gives me those three errors:

```
6: LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end. [\end{frame}]  
6: Missing $ inserted. [\end{frame}]  
6: Missing $ inserted. [\end{frame}]
```

Here is the code, I really don't know what is wrong:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  $\langle\alpha v_1,\beta v_2\rangle=\alpha\beta-\alpha\beta=0\\
  \langle\alpha v_1,\beta v_4\rangle=\alpha\beta-\alpha\beta=0$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** it works if I replace `\\` with `\newline` - but shouldn't `\\` also work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, you can't use `\\ ` in inline math. Use `align` instead.

Comment: @schtandard align would be better but this is beamer specific, try the above in article class (with no `frame`)

Comment: It is not clear what you like to obtain: in-line equations in two lines or displayed equations in two lines. In the second case is better to use `gather` environment from  the `amsmath` package and not relay on beamer specific: `\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{gather}
\langle\alpha v_1,\beta v_2\rangle=\alpha\beta-\alpha\beta=0    \\
  \langle\alpha v_1,\beta v_4\rangle=\alpha\beta-\alpha\beta=0
\end{gather}
\end{frame}
\end{document}`

Comment: the first thing, so just a linebreak within a simple math environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working with replacing `\\` with `\newline`, so my problem is solved. The other option is with two separate math environments, credit to Zarko:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
$\langle\alpha v_1,\beta v_2\rangle=\alpha\beta-\alpha\beta=0$\\
$\langle\alpha v_1,\beta v_4\rangle=\alpha\beta-\alpha\beta=0$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I really doubt in "my problem is solved". At least this is bad practice. I will never do this. Rather write two separate in-line equation (if this is demand) , each in own text line.

Comment: well, for me the most important thing was to have the problem solved. that's why after I found a working fix after even more testing I posted it here - despite it not being the sexiest way. but I added your idea as well, as you can see.

Comment: All is up to you. However, this is not an answer. This possibilities ayou already noted in your question (I didn't down vote it)